Listing (lstlisting) breaking page but putting last line of listing over footnoterule
This is the result I get when compiling my document (screenshot-snippet from the pagebreak in question):

This is the snippet of source code (the listing, the footnote is further above but a part of the text on the same output-page; also, neither version makes a difference (lstlisting and lstinputlisting produce the exact same result)):

This is my listings-package-configuration:

And these are all footnote-related stuff I included and set-up:


Also, why is it the 4th line getting printed to the bottom of the page and not the 2nd...

Update:
After playing around with it for a while, it started working as intended after removing the \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{...} lines from my configuration... I don't know why though, as it seems that LaTeX standard defintition of \footnoterule does something helping the page breaking internally... does anyone knew where I could see that specific part of LaTeX-source-code?
I would still like to have a bit more spacing in between the rule and the footnotes (as I set it up).

Also, it would be great if this problem could be solved without needing to enclose every listing in an additional enviroment.
